# NSTableView animated table cell view image

Tags: swift, macos, animation, nstableview

I have this NSTableview.

The datasource is an ArrayController.

Then I have this:

```
class shortcut: NSObject {
    @objc  var type: String
    @objc  var icon: NSImage {
        let image:NSImage = NSImage(named: type) ?? NSImage(named: "none")!
        return image
    }
```

And in Interface builder, I have an NSImageview, that is bound to TableCellView>objectValue.icon

Works fine. I'm happy. Almost...

I would like the icon to be animated. I.e. I want the icon to show, and then fade out to alpha zero.

Now, the animation logic I get, I think, but I just don't have a clue where to put the code to make it happen

Hope you do

Comment: When should the animation start?

Comment: @Willeke As soon as the associated object has changed and the table is redrawn. I think I should be able to accomplish this with the good old tableview delegate methods and a custom cell, but I'm exploring Bindings, and want to try it this way